# count comments having a hashtag with graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to count the number of comments with hashtags, Ex: #abc = 10 comments, #def = 30 comments. Is there any way to do this?
I am using the below API:
`https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/comments?access_token=`

Can anybody help me!

Comment: That is not possible